# Implementation of Multiparental Sorting Crossover

Tags: java, beginner

I implemented the Multiparental Sorting Crossover as described [here](http://www.cs.sun.ac.za/rw214/projects/cuckooSearchSudoku.pdf) in section 4.2. The (compiled) program can be run as follows:

```
$ java MPSX input.txt
```

where input.txt looks like this (the first line is the mask followed by three parents):

```
3 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 2

8 4 7 3 6 2 5 1 9

9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

4 7 9 3 6 2 5 1 8
```

As for output, it merely prints the correct result as a string.

```
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.In;
import java.io.InputStream;


public class MPSX {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String filename = args[0];
        In in = new In(filename);

        String[] Input = in.readAllLines();

        String result = solve(Input);

        System.out.println(result);

    }


    private static void swap(int[] parent_x, int[] parent_y, int index) {


        for (int i = 0; i < parent_y.length; i++) {

            if (parent_y[i] == parent_x[index]) {

                int tmp = parent_y[index];
                parent_y[index] = parent_y[i];
                parent_y[i] = tmp; 

            }

        }

    }


    private static String solve(String[] Input) {

        String result = "";

        String[] parent1str = Input[1].split(" ");
        String[] parent2str = Input[2].split(" ");
        String[] parent3str = Input[3].split(" ");

        int[] parent1 = new int[parent1str.length];
        int[] parent2 = new int[parent2str.length];
        int[] parent3 = new int[parent3str.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < parent1str.length; i++) {
            parent1[i] = Integer.parseInt(parent1str[i]);
            parent2[i] = Integer.parseInt(parent2str[i]);
            parent3[i] = Integer.parseInt(parent3str[i]);
        }

        String mask = Input[0].replaceAll("\\s","");


        for (int i = 0; i < mask.length(); i++) {

            int mask_element = Character.getNumericValue(mask.charAt(i));;

            if (mask_element == 1) {    
                result += parent1[i];
                swap(parent1, parent2,i);
                swap(parent1, parent3,i);
            }

            else if (mask_element == 2) {
                result += parent2[i];
                swap(parent2, parent1,i);
                swap(parent2, parent3,i);
            }

            else if (mask_element == 3) {
                result += parent3[i];
                swap(parent3, parent1,i);
                swap(parent3, parent2,i);
            }

        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

It is effectively the first program I wrote in Java so I know there is a lot of room for improvement and refactorization.

In particular, I am sure there is a better (more concise) way of processing the input text file. I thought of creating an array of arrays of Strings instead of 3 separate arrays but I wasn't sure how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing a line of space separated integers is repeated 4 times you can replace those with the method below:

```
private static int[] parseLineOfInts(String s) {
    String[] tokens = s.split(" ");
    int[] arr = new int[tokens.length];
    for (int j = 0; j < tokens.length; j++)
       arr[j] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[j]);
    return arr;
}
```

You can use arrays of arrays to hold 2D data. Parsing the parents becomes as below:

```
int nParents = 3;
int[][] parents = new int[nParents][];
for (int i = 0; i < nParents; i++) {
    parents[i] = parseLineOfInts(Input[i + 1]);
}
```

Note `parent1` is now `parent[0]` and so on.

You can use `parseLineOfInts` method to calculate `mask_element`s as below:

```
int[] maskElements = parseLineOfInts(Input[0]);
```

parameters and local variables should be camelcase: first word starts with lowercase, subsequent words start with upper case:

- `Input` should be `input`
- `parent_x` should be `parentX`
- `parent_y` should be `parentY`

Separate parsing and actual algorithm. Separation of concerns improves readability, testability, many other ...abilities. As a first step you can extract not string manipulation related code into a new function such that its signature becomes as below:

```
int[] solve(int[] mask, int[][] parents)
```

Comment: Thank you! One question - when you define the array of arrays like this  `int[][] parents = new int[nParents][];` how come you don't need to specify the size of the individual arrays?

Comment: Individual elements are just `null`; you can assign them later any `int[]`, no matter the length. You can leave them `null`, or assign some or all of them the same `int[]` for that matter. All of this is because Java arrays are reference types, the variables hold just the memory location of the actual value, you allocate the actual memory with `new`. You can think of `new int[m][n]` as a shorthand.